# IOS memory leak from NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsstring

I have this code below and the leaks application is saying 100% of the leak is from this line of code.

```
const unsigned char *value = sqlite3_column_text(statement, number);
if(value)
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)value]; //100%
return nil;
```

Can someone offer some insight on how to fix this.

Comment: Instruments points to where the leaked object is created, not where is leaked.

Comment: What does the "Leaked Object" column say? And are you sure this line the **ONLY** leaked object, most probably a owner of the returned value is the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

> I have this code below and the leaks application is saying 100% of the leak is from this line of code.

It doesn't mean the leak is there mate.

Answer (score 0):

It shows where the leaked block was allocated, now you need to find where you retain it and don't release. For example, if you assign it to a retaining property, you'll need to add [<propertyname> release] in the dealloc method for the class that contains the property.